# How do I install my Wacom Intuos 2 serial tablet?

Tags: 10.10, hardware, input-devices, wacom, graphics-tablet

I've seen many topics on the subjects but they are too complicated for me. I'm not confident in compiling stuff.
Is there some headache-free way to make it work under Ubuntu?
Where do I start?

Edit :
It doesn't seem to work.

```
looking at device '/devices/pnp0/00:08/tty/ttyS0':
    KERNEL=="ttyS0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pnp0/00:08':
    KERNELS=="00:08"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pnp"
    DRIVERS=="serial"
    ATTRS{id}=="PNP0501"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pnp0':
    KERNELS=="pnp0"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""


ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEMS=="pnp", ATTRS{id}=="PNP0501", ENV{ID_INPUT}="1", ENV{ID_INPUT_TABLET}="1"
ATTRS{id}==PNP0501, : commande introuvable
```

I am a bit confused. Am I right to type it in the terminal?

Comment: You shouldn't be compiling anything to make your hardware work. DKMS packages and PPAs should be all you need. Please report which guides you're using.

Comment: I try to follow to follow this:

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6546012&postcount=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serial tablepc based wacom tablets should just work without any additional attention. If they don't then we will need to do a bit of investigation from the command line (Applications > Accessories > Terminal).

First check to see if the serial port is registering correctly:

`ls /dev/ttyS*`

For each one of those you can run this command to check it's pnp information (remember to change the ttyS0 to each of the ttyS nodes found above):

`udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyS0)`

It's probably good if you copy and paste all the information here so we can see what's happening. Normally the output for a wacom should look like this:

```
looking at device '/devices/pnp0/00:0a/tty/ttyS0':
    KERNEL=="ttyS0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pnp0/00:0a':
    KERNELS=="00:0a"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pnp"
    DRIVERS=="serial"
    ATTRS{id}=="WACf004"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pnp0':
    KERNELS=="pnp0"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS=""
```

If you don't see any wacom info here then your device probably isn't a tabletpc wacom device and is probably plugged into a serial port on your computer. These devices are no longer supported in Ubuntu and you should downgrade to Karmic until support is added back in for newer xservers (1.7 and 1.9).

Comment: Here is what I got

Comment: looking at device '/devices/pnp0/00:08/tty/ttyS0':
    KERNEL=="ttyS0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pnp0/00:08':
    KERNELS=="00:08"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pnp"
    DRIVERS=="serial"
    ATTRS{id}=="PNP0501"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pnp0':
    KERNELS=="pnp0"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""

Comment: Please see my edits above for something you can try to get it working. Also note that you should post update info into your original question as comments aren't formatted.

Comment: No, you don't type it into a terminal, you add it to the file. I'll put in more detailed instructions.

Comment: OK. I added the line in the file "69-xserver-xorg-input-wacom.rules". It doesn't seem to change anything (in Gimp).

Comment: Testing it in gimp isn't the best way to see if it works, getting data from the command `xinput list` and having wacom entries, that will tell you if you have wacom hardware. (Gimp tablet support is switched off by default and you have to switch it on) If you use empathy then we can try a direct support method where you share your desktop to me and we try and sort it out.

Comment: This command doesn't show any Wacom input...

Comment: How can I contact you with empathy ?

Comment: @Gizmoatwork - doctormo@gmail.com just add me to your gmail chat.